# How to import JSON file into database

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have json file in folder `database\data\countries.json` and I have **CountriesTableSeeder.php**

I want to seed all data in **countries.json** into my table Country. But it occurs error `Trying to get property of non-object`

I have followed the step that I found, but I still got an error.

This is my model:

```
protected $fillable = ['country_name', 'iso_code'];
```

This is my seeder code:

```
public function run()
{
  $countryJson = File::get("database/data/countries.json");
  $data = json_decode($countryJson, true);
  foreach ($data as $obj) {
    Country::create(array(
      'country_name' => $obj->name, 'iso_code' => $obj->sortname
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure you have the file by testing for the existence of `$countryJson` ?

Comment: Yes, I have @user10089632
If I don't have the file, my command prompt will display error `File does not exist at path database/data/countries.json`

Comment: You have converted json into arrays, so there would be not objects `$obj->name`

Comment: So, what should I do? @Rafee

Comment: `print_r($data)` then check out. you will findout automaticall. You need to follow @ankit answers, hope that will solve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195010/json-decode-returning-error-notice-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object#25195092

Comment: How can I check from `print_r`? `php artisan migrate --seed' works in command prompt, not in my UI @Rafee

Comment: Can you validate json manually, then do `dd($data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass same variable in foreach, also make sure you have name element by checking dd($data); and you need to get array element by $obj['name'] not by $obj->name as it's not object.

```
$data = json_decode($countryJson, true);
        foreach ($data['countries'] as $obj) {
            Country::create(array(
              'country_name' => $obj['name'], 'iso_code' => $obj['sortname']
              ));
        }
```

Comment: sorry, I have made a mistake.. I have edit my question.. the variable is same but I still get the same error

Comment: did you check your array by dd($data)?, check I updated answer

Comment: how can I check dd($data)? The error displayed in command prompt, not in my UI

Comment: did you check my updated answer, you need to fetch name by $obj['name'], did you make that change?

Comment: undefined name.. but I have already get the answer. Thankyou for your help.
Let me fix your code